# How to programmatically get the list of all the Completed PullRequests in AzureDevOps?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, pull-request

I am using the following code to get the list of **All** the completed pull requests on a VSTS repository. However, the list of pull requests that is fetched, contains only a limited list of the pull requests, and not all of them. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all the completed pull requests that are created by the given identity, for the given repository
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gitHttpClient">GitHttpClient that is created for accessing vsts.</param>
        /// <param name="repositoryId">The unique identifier of the repository</param>
        /// <param name="identity">The vsts Identity of a user on Vsts</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<GitPullRequest> GetAllCompletedPullRequests(
            GitHttpClient gitHttpClient, Guid repositoryId, Identity identity)
        {
            var pullRequestSearchCriteria = new GitPullRequestSearchCriteria
            {
                Status = PullRequestStatus.Completed,
                CreatorId = identity.Id,
            };

            List<GitPullRequest> allPullRequests =  gitHttpClient.GetPullRequestsAsync(
                repositoryId,
                pullRequestSearchCriteria).Result;

            return allPullRequests;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that by default, this call to getting pull requests, will only return a limited number of pull requests ( in my case was 101). What you need to do, is to rather specify both skip, and top parameters which are stated as optional in `GetPullRequestsAsync` method's signature definition. The following code shows how to use these parameters, to return all pull requests:

**Note**: It is not clear from the definition of the method, what are the default values for skip, and top parameters ( but by varying these values I could get 1000 at each time).

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all the completed pull requests that are created by the given identity, for the given repository
/// </summary>
/// <param name="gitHttpClient">GitHttpClient that is created for accessing vsts.</param>
/// <param name="repositoryId">The unique identifier of the repository</param>
/// <param name="identity">The vsts Identity of a user on Vsts</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static List<GitPullRequest> GetAllCompletedPullRequests(
     GitHttpClient gitHttpClient, Guid repositoryId, Identity identity)
 {
     var pullRequestSearchCriteria = new GitPullRequestSearchCriteria
     {
         Status = PullRequestStatus.Completed,
         CreatorId = identity.Id,
     };
     List<GitPullRequest> allPullRequests = new List<GitPullRequest>();
     int skip = 0;
     int threshold = 1000;
     while(true){
         List<GitPullRequest> partialPullRequests =  gitHttpClient.GetPullRequestsAsync(
             repositoryId,
             pullRequestSearchCriteria,
             skip:skip, 
             top:threshold 
             ).Result;
         allPullRequests.AddRange(partialPullRequests);
         if(partialPullRequests.Length < threshold){break;}
         skip += threshold
    }
     return allPullRequests;
 }
```